# Javascript to read XML File

Tags: javascript, xml, visual-studio-2010

I am developing a web based seating plan for my office.  Below is some simple XML I have done up so I can test if my idea is working - on mouse over the desk image will turn green if desk free and red if desk taken (the image i used was sliced with Fireworks and now the rest of my dev is being done in Visual Studio 2010.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<company>
  <employee id="1" email="Test1@hotmail.com" phone="1234">Test 1</employee>
  <employee id="2" email="Test2@hotmail.com" phone="6789">Test 2</employee>
  <employee id="" email="" phone="">Free Desk</employee>
</company>
```

So the below is what I was trying in my Javascript (Note there is more code below/above for reading in the xml, etc.  The two alerts were tests I was trying - if commented in I can see that the value 1 and 2 is appearing on the webpage so I think it is reading the XML fine.

```
    //alert(xmlObj.childNodes(0).getAttribute("id"))
    //alert(xmlObj.childNodes(1).getAttribute("id"))


    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {

        **if (xmlObj.childNodes(i).getAttribute("id") == 1)** 
        {

            stringData = stringData.replace("s1.gif", "s3.gif");

        }
        else 
        {

            stringData = stringData.replace("s1.gif", "s2.gif");
        }
    }
```

However when I run I get the follwoing error on the line in Bold. Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'xmlObj.childNodes(...)' is null or not an object.  Now I'm thinking it does not like the use of i - I was hoping that for the value 1 (i.e - desk 1 it would turn red (s1.gif being replaced with s3.gif) and for other numbers desk 0 and desk 2 it would turn red.  Has anyone any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery, your code will look cleaner and it would be easier to do too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only specified 3 children for your `company` object.  Your `for` loop executes `4` times, thus overrunning the bounds of the `childNodes` object within `company`.

Change your `for` loop to `for (var i = 0; i < xmlObj.childNodes.length; i++)` and you won't have any exceptions thrown.